# how to include jar files for a specific flavor + variant combination in android build gradle file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to upgrade to gradle 4.4 and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1`.

I am receiving an error when I try to include **jar files for a specific flavor + dimension** combo and I can't figure out how to resolve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  This worked before the upgrade.

I have a `build.gradle` setup with these flavors:

```
flavorDimensions "subscription", "store"

productFlavors {
    mso {
        dimension "subscription"

    }

    ott {
        dimension "subscription"
    }

    androidTV {
        dimension "store"
    }

    amazon {
        dimension "store"
    }

}
```

These tasks work for me:

```
amazonImplementation fileTree(dir: 'src/amazon/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTVImplementation fileTree(dir: 'src/androidTV/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

but when I try to include libraries for a flavor + dimension combination like so

```
  ottAmazonImplementation fileTree(dir: 'src/ottAmazon/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

I get this error:

> Could not find method ottAmazonImplementation() for arguments [directory 'src/ottAmazon/libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Any idea how I can include libraries for a specific flavor/dimension?